# QGIS: Comparing attribute values from different layers with Expression string builder

Tags: qgis, sql, expression, string, virtual-layer

I want to compare attribute values from different attributes from multiple layers in the Expression string builder in QGIS (3.16.1) in of these layers, but I don't know how to do that.
I've tried out `aggregate` to get values from other layers, but I can only count, summarize etc. values. But I want to *compare* the values.
For example there is the attribute `"OBJID"`(from the first layer). And I want to say `OBJID` (from the first layer) `= OBJID` (from another layer). So that all objects in the first layer are displayed where this equation is true.

Comment: Please can you provide some examples of your data so we can understand the requirements

Comment: For example there is the attribute "OBJID"(from the first layer). And I want to say OBJID (from the first layer) = OBJID(from another layer). So that all objects in the first layer are displayed if this equation is true.

Comment: I wonder if attribute() or get_feature() may be of some use? https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#record-and-attributes-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two possibilities. Instead of using expressions, creating a virtual layer is probably the easier way:

**Solution 1: Creating a virtual layer**

What you can do is create a virtual layer and add this query:

```
SELECT Lay1.OBJID_1 as o1, Lay2.OBJID_2 as o2 
FROM Layer_1 as lay1, Layer_2 as lay2
WHERE o1=o2
```

**Solution 2: Using QGIS expressions**

If you want to use QGIS epressions, you can use the expression `get_feature`, where you set the (other) layer as 1st argument (here: `'Layer_2'`), the fieldname you are interested in as 2nd argument (here: `'OBJID_2'`) and the value (here = `"OBJID_1"`) as third argument. Be carful with single ' ' and dobble " " quatation marks. Now you have the feature from Layer_2 in the field OBJID_2 that has a value that equals OBJID_1.

For visualisation purpose, this expression here creates a line for points on Layer_1 to those points on Layer_2 that have the same value for OBJID_2 as the OBJID_1 on layer 1:

```
make_line (
   ( $geometry ) ,
   geometry ( 
      get_feature ( 
         'Layer_2', 
         'OBJID_2', 
         "OBJID_1" )
   )
)
```

See:

[image]

If you are in the expression editor somewhere on layer_1 and want to get an array of all features of layer_2, use the following expression: `array_foreach(array,expression)`. This iterates for every element of the input-array (1st argument) over an expression (2nd argument) and outputs the collected results of the iterated expression.

We create an input-array containing the numbers from 1 to the number of the last feature with the expression `generate_series(start,stop)` where start is 1 and stop is the number of features the layer contains. We can get this number with the expression `to_int ( layer_property ('Layer_2', 'feature_count') )` - we have to convert it to integer `to_int()`

So now we are ready to start going through each feature of layer_2. We get the features with the expression `get_feature_by_id ( layer , feature_id )` and we can now set as feature_id the integers from the array created before: we reference it by `@element`. All together, it looks like:

```
array_foreach (
   generate_series ( 
      1,
      to_int ( layer_property (
         'Layer_2', 'feature_count')
      )
   ),
   ( get_feature_by_id ( 
      'Layer_2', 
      @element)
   )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps me.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an **attribute join** (Processing > Vector general > Join attributes by field value).  Using your example, the tool's *input layer* = Layer_1, and *Table field* = Layer_1's OBJID.  Likewise, *input layer 2* = Layer_2, and *Table field 2* = Layer_2's OBJID.

Following the join, open the output layer's attribute table and click the *Select features using an expression* button (yellow box with a superimposed sigma).  In the left-hand panel, insert the expression "OBJID" = "OBJID_2" (include the double-quotes).  Voila!  the selected records represent the cases where the expression is true.

Comment: Thank you! That helps me too.